# How to fix SyntaxError: Unexpected token ... while using socket.io in my local machine

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I am trying to use socket.io on one of a simple project but when I run the same on my local machine I am getting this bug. I am not able to figure out what is going wrong my index.js is as follows

```
const app = require("express")();
    const http = require("http").Server(app);
    const io = require("socket.io")(http);
    const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

    app.get("/", function(req, res) {
        res.render("index.ejs");
    });

    http.listen(port, function() {
        console.log("Listening on *:" + port);
    });
```

The full log is here

```
Desktop/chat/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:347
      ...options
      ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
    at createScript (vm.js:74:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:116:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:533:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (Desktop/chat/node_modules/ws/index.js:3:19)
```

My node version is 8.0

Comment: npm ERR! missing script: build

Comment: It seems possible that something isn't properly installed, either socket.io or nodejs or you need a newer node.js version.  You don't show the actual line of code that fails, but that looks like it may be object spread syntax.  I think you need at least node v8.6 or v8.21 with some custom command line flags (to enable it).

Comment: I have updated nodejs how will I debug this?

Comment: Updated nodejs to what version?

Comment: 8.0.0 is the version I am using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like it's probably the object spread operator.  If you showed the actual line of code that causes the error, we could see for sure.

You will need at least node v8.6 to get support for the object spread operator by default.  Starting with node v8.21, it could be enabled via command line flags.